# How do i hide session information from url after successful authentication through facebook connect?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook connect in one of my website. For this i have used php sdk library.

I am using following code:

```
<?php
  require APP_PHYSICAL_PATH.'includefiles.php';
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'req_perms' => 'email,user_location',
        'next'=>APP_URL.'views/search.php?validate=true'

        )
);
?>  
   <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
    <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
  </a>
```

The problem is that after successful authentication it goes to search page but it shows session information in the url. For e.g.

```
http://mydomain/views/search.php?validate=true&session={"session_key"%1A"4.7REQluh3EVBGKiA5m8cNlg__.6600.1700968000-900001178893860"%
```

I want that this session information should not be visible. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Please help me on this

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem was the following:

- When the user clicks the Facebook login button, a popup window appears (preferably without the URL input bar). Also, you can pass a 'display' => 'popup' parameter to the getLoginUrl method, as this will use another layout for the Facebook connect page which is more suitable for popup windows.
- When the Facebook login and permission granting is successful, Facebook redirects you to that URL you don't want to show.
- On the page you're redirected to, you should echo a javascript which closes the window.

Another solution would be to do this entire connect stuff inside an iframe (though I haven't tested this approach).

Comment: Hi Imi thanks for replying, i have passed 'display'=>'popup' parameter to the getLoginUrl method but no popup window appears it opens in full page.

Comment: You have to implement the popup window in JavaScript, the 'display' => 'popup' is just to alter the layout of the Facebook connect page to look better in a popup window.

Comment: Hi, i have used  following code:                                  <a onclick="window.open('<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>');">
        <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
      </a>
But after successful authentication it redirects to the search page but in the popup window with session information in the url.

Comment: You shouldn't pass the search URL in the 'next' parameter of getLoginUrl. Instead you may pass an URL which saves the facebook session information and then outputs a `<script type="text/javascript">window.close()</script>` to close the window. Additionally, you may include a `window.opener.history.go(0)` to refresh your original browser window, or you can include `window.opener.location.href=<search page URL>` to open the search page in the original window.

Comment: You can store that serialized Facebook session in your database, or in your own session, it's up to you, but that session info is required to make authenticated requests towards Facebook API. So my advice is to set the 'next' parameter to a PHP script which does the session saving, and then output that window closing javascript code.